# Получить все поля и методы класса, исключая наследуемые

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Пробовал я сделать так:

```
type.GetFields(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

Не возвращает ничего. 
Пробую добавить Public, NonPublic, Instance, Static - что-то появилось, но не всё.

```
type.GetFields(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
```

Самое странное, что даже вообще без флагов он не возвращает все методы и поля =/

Как получить все, кроме наследуемых? Независимо от модификатора доступа и статичности или нестатичности.

Цель: создать json-объект структуры проекта (массив классов со всеми полями и методами). В последствии этот файл будет применятся другим человеком для рисования диаграммы на web-странице.

Проект учебный, так что смысла в конечной цели искать не стоит.

Ссылка на сам проект для рефлексии: https://github.com/MrModest/Tetris
Он вроде небольшой. Если нужны именно какие-то обрывки сюда, то пишите.

Пример класса:

```
public class Block
{
    public static int Length { get; set; } = 30;
    public static Size Size { get { return new Size(Length, Length); } }

    public static Rectangle GetRect(int hPos, int vPos)
    {
        return new Rectangle(new Point(hPos * Length, vPos * Length), Size);
    }

    public Block(int hPos, int vPos)
    {
        if (hPos < 0 || vPos < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Отсчёт позиций (hPos и vPos) идёт с нуля и не может быть отрицательным!");
        }

        this.hPos = hPos;
        this.vPos = vPos;
    }

    public Block(int hPos, int vPos, Color color)
    {
        if (hPos < 0 || vPos < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Отсчёт позиций (hPos и vPos) идёт с нуля и не может быть отрицательным!");
        }

        this.hPos = hPos;
        this.vPos = vPos;
        this.Color = color;
    }

    public int hPos { get; set; }
    public int vPos { get; set; }
    public Point LocationPoint { get { return new Point(hPos * Length, vPos * Length); } }
    public Color Color { get; set; } = Color.Gray;
    public Rectangle Rect { get { return new Rectangle(LocationPoint, Size); } }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color), Rect);
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 2);
        pen.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, Rect);
    }
}
```

Пример возврата (после пропуска через свои классы упрощения):

```
{
    "Modifier": "publicMod",
    "Name": "Block",
    "FullName": "Tetris.Block",
    "Namespace": "Tetris",
    "BaseClass": null,
    "Attributes": [],
    "Operations": [{
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Int32",
            "Name": "get_Length",
            "Parameters": [],
            "IsStatic": true,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Void",
            "Name": "set_Length",
            "Parameters": [{
                    "Type": "Int32",
                    "Name": "value"
                }
            ],
            "IsStatic": true,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Drawing.Size",
            "Name": "get_Size",
            "Parameters": [],
            "IsStatic": true,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Drawing.Rectangle",
            "Name": "GetRect",
            "Parameters": [{
                    "Type": "Int32",
                    "Name": "hPos"
                }, {
                    "Type": "Int32",
                    "Name": "vPos"
                }
            ],
            "IsStatic": true,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Int32",
            "Name": "get_hPos",
            "Parameters": [],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Void",
            "Name": "set_hPos",
            "Parameters": [{
                    "Type": "Int32",
                    "Name": "value"
                }
            ],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Int32",
            "Name": "get_vPos",
            "Parameters": [],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Void",
            "Name": "set_vPos",
            "Parameters": [{
                    "Type": "Int32",
                    "Name": "value"
                }
            ],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Drawing.Point",
            "Name": "get_LocationPoint",
            "Parameters": [],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Drawing.Color",
            "Name": "get_Color",
            "Parameters": [],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Void",
            "Name": "set_Color",
            "Parameters": [{
                    "Type": "Color",
                    "Name": "value"
                }
            ],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Drawing.Rectangle",
            "Name": "get_Rect",
            "Parameters": [],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Void",
            "Name": "Draw",
            "Parameters": [{
                    "Type": "Graphics",
                    "Name": "g"
                }
            ],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.String",
            "Name": "ToString",
            "Parameters": [],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": true
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Boolean",
            "Name": "Equals",
            "Parameters": [{
                    "Type": "Object",
                    "Name": "obj"
                }
            ],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": true
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Int32",
            "Name": "GetHashCode",
            "Parameters": [],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": true
        }, {
            "Modifier": "publicMod",
            "ReturnType": "System.Type",
            "Name": "GetType",
            "Parameters": [],
            "IsStatic": false,
            "IsAbstract": false,
            "IsVirtual": false
        }
    ],
    "IsInterface": false,
    "IsAbstract": false,
    "IsStatic": false,
    "IsEnum": false,
    "IsSealed": false
}
```

Comment: будет лучше, если добавишь небольшой пример классов с полями и ожидаемый результат

Comment: _вообще без флагов он не возвращает все методы и поля_ - по умолчанию возвращаются публичные instance поля

Comment: @Grundy добавил ссылку на проект

Comment: Набор флагов выглядит правильным. Но, как я понимаю, тебе не хватает в выводе свойств. Для этого нужно либо добавить GetProperties, либо вместо вызовов трех функций вызывать одну: getMembers

Comment: Вместо ссылки добавь лучше пример base/derived с разными вариантами и пример вывода

Comment: @Grundy добавил... пример "чистого" json, который возвращает Type дать не могу, так как тот почему-то не сериализуется.. возвращает строку вроде `"Tetris.Block, Tetris, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"` вместо json-объекта

Comment: @Grundy впрочем убедился, что и до преобразования в свои типы `GetField()` для данного класса вообще ничего не возвращает

Comment: Не возвращает, потому что в этом классе нет полей - есть свойства

Comment: @Grundy запращивать Property?

Comment: посмотри мой комментарий выше, я написал пару вариантов

Comment: @Grundy а как получить модификаторы доступа у свойств? не вижу у них IsPrivate/IsPublic и т.п.

Comment: @Grundy и вариант с MemberInfo мне не подходит, как я понял, ибо он не содержит нужных мне полей для описания полей/свойств и методов

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69352/discussion-between-grundy-and-mr-modest).